# RSA Algorithm is not working for certain numbers

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

I have a homework that includes handling user login and register. For that the teacher told us to use the RSA Algorithm to encrypt the passwords of the users. My problem is with the RSA. I am trying to write it to encrypt only 1 integer and after that I will write a new method that encrypts a string.
So at this moment, my code works for some integers and for others it fails pretty bad.
This is the header file

```
#ifndef _RSA_
#define _RSA_

#include <cmath>
#include <string>

// A class that defines the RSA algorithm
class RSA {
    private:
        int p, q, n, z, d = 0, e;

    public:
        RSA();
        int gcd(int a, int b);
        int encrypt(int m);
        int decrypt(int c);
    
};

#endif
```

And this is the file where I implement those functions.

```
#include "./RSA.h"

RSA::RSA() {
    this->p = 3;
    this->q = 11;
    this->z = (this->p - 1) * (this->q - 1);
    this->n = this->p * this->q;

    for (this->e = 2; this->e < this->z; this->e++) {
        if (this->gcd(this->e, this->z) == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
        int x = (i * this->z) + 1;
        if (x % this->e == 0) {
            this->d = x / this->e;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int RSA::gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int RSA::encrypt(int m) {
    return (int)pow(m, e) % this->n;
}

int RSA::decrypt(int c) {
    return (int)pow(c, d) % this->n;
}
```

Now I am going to provide you with some numbers that work and some numbers that do not work.
Saying that the numbers work I mean that after I decrypt the result of encrypt method I get the initial number.
It works for 1,2,6,7,8,9,10(it returns 10 for encrypted part and 10 for decrypted), 11(same as 10), 12(same as 11), 13, 14, 15, 16. I tested numbers in the range [1, 17] and it failed for 3,4,5,17. It returns completely random numbers for this 4 numbers. Also, I tried it on other number ranges and the result was the same.

Comment: `pow()` is probably not the right tool to do this, you should find a better way to calculate those powers of integer values.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of a better way please?

Comment: `pow()` actually return a decimal and convert back to an integer. So it could encounter rounding errors. Probably should write your own `pow()`?

Comment: I wrote my own pow. And it still does not decrypt the right way.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that people could easily paste and run that demonstrates your problem. With a `main` function and some hardcoded example data preferably.

Comment: unexpected/wrong != random. Do you get same output for same input or not? That makes an important difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with small numbers like that it's easy to exceed the limits of int with exponentiation. If you make your own pow, it should apply the modulo after every step:

```
// computes x**y % n
int custom_pow(int x, int y, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    for(;y;y--) {
        res = (res*x) % n;
    }
    return res;
}
```